# Editing questions to solve XY problems

Tags: discussion, edits

In the following post, it became evident after some comments that the user had an [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem:

[find lpClassName of started application to be used in FindWindow wniapi c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16932556/find-lpclassname-of-started-application-to-be-used-in-findwindow-wniapi-c)

With the OP's permission, I suggested an edit to make the actual problem more apparent, which was narrowly rejected:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2256353

Is it unacceptable to edit a question to better represent the real problem the OP was trying to solve, or did I just do a poor job at it?

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I think this is an acceptable edit and that you did as good a job as possible (including the comment to your edit). This *is* somewhat hard to review, especially when reviewers are hunting for badges. Curious about how to handle this, so +1.

Comment: The edit was correct. You were a victim of 'possible case of audit'. Since audits are generally those which have a (huge/obvious) change in titles of the posts ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good point, as I see it the actual question discussed here is "Can we rewrite posts completely, given the author permission?"

Well, I would say "Yes" but still, we're talking about very major change in the post turning it into something else so many others won't agree to this.

So, what to do? Here are a few options I can think of:

1. Go to chat with the post author and tell him/her in real time when you post the suggestion then he/she can approve it instanty.
2. Suggest the edit like you did; in case it's rejected ask the author to edit taking what you wrote by linking to the suggested edit.

Comment: Are you suggesting my question had an XY problem? ;) FYI, option 2 is what I ended up doing.