# How / whether to revert an edit to a question by an OP when lacking reputation to revert

Tags: support, edits

After I posted an answer and engaged the OP in comments, he edited the question so my answer now makes no sense, and added to question. It doesn't look like I have reputation to revert edits, and I'm not even sure yet what the policy is, so this would be a good example to learn from.

reference: [How can I run the same command multiple times in series and capture all exit codes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/428387/how-can-i-run-the-same-command-multiple-times-in-series-and-capture-all-exit-cod)

EDIT: At some point, someone suggested that this question might be a duplicate of [Change to question invalidates my answer, what to do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286803/change-to-question-invalidates-my-answer-what-to-do) , but it is not, and the answer of user PolyGeo was the perfect answer for me. The primary intention of my question, though unclearly stated, was what someone should do if they lack the reputation to revert an edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If an edit to a question strands an answer so that it no longer makes sense, then I think that edit should be rolled back.

If you do not have sufficient reputation to perform the rollback yourself, then you could try to find someone else that can:

- ask in chat of that site
- make a Meta post on that site
- flag a moderator on that site

Answer (score 3):

I've typically taken the other, somewhat more passive agressive approach - letting the user know, via comments that its not cool.

I actually think OP was trying to debug his code *in* the question as he went along. Its a bit of an odd thing, but feels like more of a lack of "getting how things work" than an attempt at the ol [chameleon question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)

I'd actually suggest a small hack here "As per revision X of this question" basically lets the reader know that the question has changed *and* ensures your question is relevant through minor changes. I'd also let the user know that, well, this makes your answer irrelevant so... could you kindly refrain from actually changing the core question.